# Does not work yup with react-hook-form or material ui

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm trying to use react-hook-form library to validate a form. when the form is empty and i click "sand" it should give an error but it doesn't show anything.I don’t understand why it doesn’t work. I did everything like here(https://codesandbox.io/s/928po918qr).
InputField and IMaskPhoneInput return <TextField {props} />

```
import { IMaskPhoneInput, InputField } from "../../../common/model";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import cn from "classnames";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as yup from "yup";

export const PopupCallMe = (props) => {
  const SignupSchema = yup.object().shape({
    phone: yup
      .string()
      .transform((value) => {
        return value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
      })
      .min(11, "Некорректный номер телефона")
      .required("Обязательное поле"),
    firstName: yup
      .string()
      .required("Обязательное поле")
      .matches(/^[A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё]+$/, "Недопустимое имя")
      .min(2, "Недопустимое имя")
      .max(15, "Недопустимое имя")
      .typeError("Некорректное тип"),
  });

  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    validationSchema: SignupSchema,
    mode: "onTouched",
    reValidateMode: "onBlur",
  });

  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log(values);
  };

  const [showDescr, setShowDescr] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("order");

  const handleChangeCheck = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className={s.popup_wrap}>
      <div className={s.title}>Перезвонить мне</div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div>
          <IMaskPhoneInput
            autoFocus
            fullWidth
            name={"phone"}
            mask={"+{7} (000) 000-00-00"}
            color="primary"
            label={"Телефон"}
            placeholder={"+7 (950) 356-55-44"}
            inputRef={register}
            error={errors.phone}
            helperText={errors.phone && errors.phone.message}
          />
          <div className={s.subtext}>
            Оператор перезвонит в течение 1 часа (с 9:00 до 21:00 по местному
            времени)
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className={s.addName}>
          <InputField
            fullWidth
            name={"firstName"}
            type={"text"}
            label={"Моё имя"}
            placeholder={"Глеб"}
            inputRef={register}
            error={errors.firstName}
            helperText={errors.firstName && errors.firstName.message}
          />
        </div>
        <div className={s.wrapButton}>
          <button className={cn("button", s.button)}>Отправить</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You don't have a submit button

Comment: Solved a problem
add in useForm `resolver: yupResolver(SignupSchema),`
and at Input `{...register("name")}`